# ImportError: No module named input.evdev

Tags: python, minecraft, pyglet

So whenever I try to run http://codeflow.org/entries/2010/dec/09/minecraft-like-rendering-experiments-in-opengl-4/ I always get the error

```
from pyglet.input.evdev import get_devices
ImportError: No module named input.evdev
```

How would I fix this? 
I am on Mac OSX 10.6.8 running Python 2.7.3. I have pyglet 1.1.4 and gletools (i forget the version).

Answer (score 1):

"I've now found that the piece of example code will only run with OpenGL 4.0. Changing that line to not include `.evdev` fixed the problem" is quote from a similar problem found [here](http://osdir.com/ml/python-pyglet-user/2011-03/msg00037.html). Maybe it will help you out...

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer, just a long comment:

Go to a terminal and type

```
python
>>> import pyglet
>>> pyglet.__file__
```

You should get some output which will show you the path to the `pyglet` module. Go to that directory and confirm that there is a subdirectory called `input`, and a file inside `input` called `evdev.py`.

You should find some kind of error. Maybe the file does not exist, or has the wrong permissions, or...?